# High swing (Low-voltage) cascode current mirror pole

Tags: mosfet, high-frequency, low-voltage, current-mirror, time-constant

I have been trying to figure out extracting the exact derivation for the poles, I am only struggling with figuring how the author got pole 8. I am using the small signal for the high swing cascode current mirror. But however I analyze it, I can't find how he approximated the equation as provided.
[image]
[image]
[image]
I need help on how to find the time constant for the node looking at the M8 source.

1. the small signal model
2. the analysis to acquire the Resistant the capacitance is looking at the node.

tried many approaches, even the wrong ideas to know how the result obtained
[image]
[image]